# Struggle to mix two shader using a factor

Tags: shaders

I have some struggle to apply a factor to a shader mix.
I have a windows how got scratches (shader A) and dirt (shader B) but just in the corners (factor).

So logically if I use a mix (shader, color, mix, add, multiply, I tried everything) it should put the dirt in the corners and the scratch in the middle. But unfortunately no. it just puts the scratch everywhere and skip the dirty...

[image]

but if you switch A and B it work

[image]

Can some one please help me to understand why the factor not work ?

Have a nice day.

***UPDATE***

Here is the complete shader tree

The red "edges" node block is a function I use to find sharp edges. And where the edges are I put dirt on it.

[image]

Comment: Invert your factor before connecting.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are doing (as you never show the full setup) and what you want (is it you last picture and in that case, why don't you use it?), could you please share your file and tell more, where are the scratches supposed to be? On the corners like in your last image?

Comment: I think he wants the "opposite" of the last image - dirt (brown) in the corners/edges and scratches (white) in the middle. Solution: use Mix Color set to _mix_ and invert the mix factor.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see where you are mixing anything there.

Comment: @Christopher Bennett OK I'm giving a try

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Inverting the factor is what I would suggest too - but if this was the only problem, I would expect it to look like the bottom image - which according to the question was achieved by switching what is plugged in the input sockets. So, without switching the result should have been correct even without inverting the factor. But instead it seems to give a result as if the factor was 1 or 0 everywhere, just showing one of the inputs. That's why I'm voting to close this question for it needs more clarity. It does not show how the textures are mixed, but there must be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to overlay the corners and the scratches images you can invert the corners color, mix the 2 images into a *Color > Mix Color* (in *Multiply* mode), and use this mix as a factor between the dirt image and the glass material:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I'm looking for!
For the mask you use a self drawn picture?

Comment: what do you mean by "self drawn picture"?

Comment: I just update my poste so you can see that with the "edges" block I automatically find the corners.
I see that your Mask is a .png so i imagine that you painted it with texture paint right ?

Comment: I've copy-pasted the textures you show

Comment: You made an image capture from my image capture ?

Comment: yes I've extracted the texture part of your screenshot, as you can see it's exactly the same

Comment: you'r a genus. I think i will take this method. 

But I would like to understand why my method is not working. Is that because It's a map and not a picture? Because blender is not able to see the white ?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're trying to do the same as me, it looks like you're trying to create a Bump map, if you're trying to do so the mix is incorrect, the Bump node needs to be the last before the Normal input of the Principled BSDF

Comment: Yes, I do a also a bump map to give more realism. And the bump map work pretty good. It's for the colors that I have struggled...

Comment: the simplest would have been to prepare your mask in an image editor like Photoshop, if you really want to do it in Blender, like I did, you can do it the way I did, I inverted the corners image so that I could add it to the scratches image

Comment: And I don't understand why a mask.jpg work and not my red "edges" node block. I mean, when I isolate it I have this beautiful black and white texture on the windows. Why can't I use it as a factor?

Comment: The problem with that method is that I have to make a picture for every part that I make... And with the "red edges node bloke" I was able to generate it automatically... But it's fine, I will understand how to make it automatically in a future when I became a shader professional. 
Thank you a lot for your quick answer. Some time a simple way is the best one ;)